# Deploying and Registering Com Interop interfaces

Tags: wix, com-interop, heat

I am attempting to deploy my new .net Com visible interfaces.  After installation my new .dll could be loaded by my app.  There is a requirement to cast one of the interfaces which is not working.

I am harvesting my wix xml with the use of Heat.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\heat.exe" file "MYComConnect.dll" /out "dll_fragment_12_2015.wxs"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\heat.exe" file "MYComConnect.tlb" -scom /out "tlb_fragment_12_2015.wxs"
```

To know that it is not a coding problem with my .dll I have registered my .dll and .tlb with regasm and everything works fine.

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" "MYComConnect.dll" /tlb
```

I then did a registry comparison of what is added by regasm and what my wix installer adds.

I noticed that the following folders keys were added by regasm but were NOT added by my wix install (corresponding values were also added by regasm but I will not post it all)

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{6D8A24A9-9723-4934-9852-D8877BBBB9F6}
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{6D8A24A9-9723-4934-9852-D8877BBBB9F6}\ProxyStubClsid32
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{6D8A24A9-9723-4934-9852-D8877BBBB9F6}\TypeLib
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{721AE779-4A04-4FFE-B317-FE2355DE31FA}
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{721AE779-4A04-4FFE-B317-FE2355DE31FA}\ProxyStubClsid32
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{721AE779-4A04-4FFE-B317-FE2355DE31FA}\TypeLib
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{A001212B-8F67-42B6-BAA6-D61D6B34FC26}
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{A001212B-8F67-42B6-BAA6-D61D6B34FC26}\ProxyStubClsid32
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{A001212B-8F67-42B6-BAA6-D61D6B34FC26}\TypeLib
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{F293DBB5-471C-4D71-80CB-C3B30EBDFE10}
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{F293DBB5-471C-4D71-80CB-C3B30EBDFE10}\ProxyStubClsid32
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{F293DBB5-471C-4D71-80CB-C3B30EBDFE10}\TypeLib
```

It seems that my wix install only adds registry keys in Wow6432Node.  Regasm adds keys to both.

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{6D8A24A9-9723-4934-9852-D8877BBBB9F6}
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{6D8A24A9-9723-4934-9852-D8877BBBB9F6}\ProxyStubClsid32
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{6D8A24A9-9723-4934-9852-D8877BBBB9F6}\TypeLib
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{721AE779-4A04-4FFE-B317-FE2355DE31FA}
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{721AE779-4A04-4FFE-B317-FE2355DE31FA}\ProxyStubClsid32
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{721AE779-4A04-4FFE-B317-FE2355DE31FA}\TypeLib
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{A001212B-8F67-42B6-BAA6-D61D6B34FC26}
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{A001212B-8F67-42B6-BAA6-D61D6B34FC26}\ProxyStubClsid32
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{A001212B-8F67-42B6-BAA6-D61D6B34FC26}\TypeLib
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{F293DBB5-471C-4D71-80CB-C3B30EBDFE10}
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{F293DBB5-471C-4D71-80CB-C3B30EBDFE10}\ProxyStubClsid32
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{F293DBB5-471C-4D71-80CB-C3B30EBDFE10}\TypeLib
```

The other difference I noted is that heat has the following entry for each class whereas Regasm does not have it

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{FB1D6314-4409-46E9-BD92-DDD99D110CDE}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}\: ""
```

I have read that it does not matter where the interfaces are registered as they do not depend on bitness however after a comparison of what regasm does and what heat harvests it appears that if the interfaces are not added to both the x64 and x32 registry then it does not work.

Just the first RegistryValue element from my heat harvested interface fragment looks like this below.  This adds the element to the Wow6432Node.

```
<Fragment>
  <DirectoryRef Id="MYAPPCOMINTEROP">
    <Component Id="Com_Interop_TLB" Guid="{F8F60B35-0270-4569-8F0F-9D09398C72D8}">
      <File Id="fil460187E36ECD90A7A9A00591ADB1C5CB" Name="MYComConnect.tlb" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\..\MYComConnectReferencedDLL\MYComConnect.tlb" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="Interface\{6D8A24A9-9723-4934-9852-D8877BBBB9F6}" Value="_MYAppConnect" Type="string" Action="write" />
```

So in the absence of another solution I want to follow what regasm does with the registry entries, how can I achieve that with my Wix xml.

**Edit - Further information**

1. Target computer is Win 7 x64 with Office 2010 x86
2. My Main App has Target CPU x86
3. Com Visible .dll Target **CPU is AnyCPU** (the dll is used by Office and my App)
4. MSI is x64 (as I already have a context menu .dll which needs to write registry items to x64 so that Windows' x64 Explorer will read them.

I hope this does not complicate things but what my COM Visible dll does is [allows me to call code in a VSTO addin.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608621.aspx) I dont think this code is necessary as I can get my custom object from Office and cast it to my custom interface with no problems if I use regasm to register my .dll and create the tlb file.

I actually unregistered everything on my development PC and installed my final MSI.  My .dll works and I can cast my interface.  What assumptions can I make from this? I am assuming that the problem lies with my Com .dll and building it and thus my problem has nothing to do with my heat harvesting and wix xml coding.

**Update 2 of Problem**
I obtained a second PC with Visual Studio on it. I Copied my Com .dll project on it and built it. I Created the .tlb file with Tlbexp.exe on this PC.  I then installed this with my MSI and I can now cast the COM interface.

So I now have to work out why building it on one PC it works and on another it does not.  The most major difference right now is that the PC that works has Win 7 on it, the one that does not work is Win 10.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to know the bitness of your app and your MSI build(s).

A 32-bit app will have a 32-bit registry view, and will need CLSID references to 32-bit COM dlls. Interface entries may refer to a ProxyStub CLSID that will also need to be 32-bit and that means that the interface entries have bitness. That's my understanding anyway, so your COM Dll needs CLSID and Interface references in HKCR (HKL\Software\Classes) in both native and 32-bit WoW6432 if it has both 64 and 32-bit callers.

In WiX, you'd add Win64=yes to the component to make it 64-bit. If you have 32 and 64-bit callers to your COM, then in a 64-bit MSI you'd add both 32 and 64-bit components for your COM, and in a separate 32-bit MSI just the 32-bit components. Heat doesn't know the bitness of your final MSI, so it's up to you to use Win64 on components to target the required registry view.